# which Blackberry App World submission files are required for release

Tags: blackberry, structure, submission, blackberry-world

Really sorry to be asking a bit of an off topic question, but we've got a Blackberry 5.0 app that we need to get up in the app store asap.

I have a zip file that contains the following

[Root Folder]
.alx
[Child folder<5.0.0>]
.cod
.csi
.cso
.debug
.jad
.jar
[/Child Folder]
[/Root Folder]

Anyone know if this can bu submitted as is, or I wasn't sure if this was pre haps a debug build, and needed recompiling for release (a la iOS). I've noticed it doesn't contain a release.xml file or a devices.txt, and also I have a feeling the child folder should be renamed to "Appname_5.0.0"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all make sure that your code is `sign` successfully with `Blackberry code sign certificate`. Make one zip file with `cod & jad` file from your `deliverables > Standard` folder. Create account in [Blackberry vendor portal](https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/login_input.do?pageId=0)  Than `Manage Product` to upload app . Follow the instruction and fill required info (app detail , rating ,screen shot, icon ...) to your App. After submit app it will show app Status in `Pending review`  . After few days your app will be ready for `post for sale`. Than you can see app in [Blackberry App World](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/) As per my experience with Blackberry it will take minimum 10 to 14 day for Approval .

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have the account etc all set up. So just to be clear the only files in need to zip and upload are the .cod & .jad? I read here [link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25819/Options_for_a_zip_file_for_a_release_664581_11.jsp) that you also needed a release.xml and a devices.txt, but if I can ignore them then I'm good to go.

Comment: Creating a ZIP file for release in the format specified by the link is to provide the information in the ZIP file rather than entering it on the web site during submission. They try to explain that a bit on the previous page: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25819/Create_a_release_664046_11.jsp The process does appear to be optional.